# Spring-PetClinic with Docker using Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: spring, docker, jenkins, containers, pipeline

First of all I'm still new in this area and I don't have a clear view in some places yet.
I've been trying to build a pipeline for days where the Spring-PetClinic project runs both in a Docker container and ends up in a Docker Hub repository. Below is the error message and the build processes stops after checkout. I think there is the problem, which i don't know how to solve this.

```
Jenkinsversion: 2.414.3
Dockerversion:  4.24.0
```

Error-Message while build-now process by Jenkins:

```
Obtained Jenkinsfile from git https://github.com/Can-24/spring-petclinic.git
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in C:\data\jenkins_home\workspace\spring-petclinic-docker
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Checkout SCM)
[Pipeline] checkout
The recommended git tool is: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
using credential docker-hub-credentials
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe rev-parse --resolve-git-dir C:\data\jenkins_home\workspace\spring-petclinic-docker\.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe config remote.origin.url https://github.com/Can-24/spring-petclinic.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/Can-24/spring-petclinic.git
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.42.0.windows.2'
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/Can-24/spring-petclinic.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/main^{commit}" # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 08dcff1c93944a31132693c0e9df151fb15a66e9 (refs/remotes/origin/main)
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe checkout -f 08dcff1c93944a31132693c0e9df151fb15a66e9 # timeout=10
Commit message: "21st. commit"
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe rev-list --no-walk 895efde9aefe8f6d28bdbdefec15692cd0b759c0 # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withCredentials
Masking supported pattern matches of %DOCKER_HUB_CREDENTIALS% or %DOCKER_HUB_CREDENTIALS_PSW%
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Also:   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.ErrorAction$ErrorId: 0e9bbeb0-bf7f-4cf2-bc7e-0d34208be412
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such field found: field java.lang.String username
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.unclassifiedField(SandboxInterceptor.java:402)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:386)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$7.call(Checker.java:375)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:379)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.LoggingInvoker.getProperty(LoggingInvoker.java:121)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.withEnvBlock(ModelInterpreter.groovy:431)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsDefaultGroovyMethods.callClosureForMapEntry(CpsDefaultGroovyMethods:5361)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsDefaultGroovyMethods.collect(CpsDefaultGroovyMethods:3563)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsDefaultGroovyMethods.collect(CpsDefaultGroovyMethods:3580)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.withEnvBlock(ModelInterpreter.groovy:429)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.call(ModelInterpreter.groovy:78)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.withCredentialsBlock(ModelInterpreter.groovy:476)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:73)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:65)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor225.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:152)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:146)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:136)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:275)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:146)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:187)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:423)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:331)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:295)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:97)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:139)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at jenkins.util.ErrorLoggingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(ErrorLoggingExecutorService.java:51)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
Finished: FAILURE
```

```
checkout-Logfile:
The recommended git tool is: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
No credentials specified
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe rev-parse --resolve-git-dir C:\data\jenkins_home\workspace\spring-petclinic-docker\.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe config remote.origin.url https://github.com/Can-24/spring-petclinic.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/Can-24/spring-petclinic.git
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.42.0.windows.2'
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/Can-24/spring-petclinic.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe rev-parse "origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
```

The following are my Docker and my Jenkins file
Dockerfile:

```
# Use an OpenJDK base image
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim

# Create a working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the compiled Spring Boot application (JAR file) into the working directory
COPY target/spring-petclinic-*.jar app.jar

# Open the port 8081
EXPOSE 8081

# Start the application at container startup
CMD ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

And the Jenkinsfile:

```
#!groovy
pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
       DOCKER_HUB_CREDENTIALS = credentials('docker-hub-credentials')
       DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME = "${DOCKER_HUB_CREDENTIALS.username}"
       DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD = "${DOCKER_HUB_CREDENTIALS.password}"
    }

    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                git 'https://github.com/Can-24/spring-petclinic.git'
            }
        }

        stage('Build and Package Spring PetClinic') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn clean package'
            }
        }

        stage('Build and Publish Docker Image') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh './mvnw spring-boot:build-image'
                    dockerImage = docker.build("can24/spring-petclinic:${BUILD_NUMBER}")

                    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'docker-hub-credentials', usernameVariable: 'DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD')]) {
                        docker.withRegistry('https://index.docker.io/v1/', 'docker-hub-credentials') {
                            dockerImage.push()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Run Docker Container') {
            steps {
                sh 'docker run -d -p 8081:8081 can24/spring-petclinic:${BUILD_NUMBER}'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully someone can help me with this. I kind of realize that I'm almost there but kind of not either.